# Can I show a different image during each loop with Matplotlib? Image doen't appear during running

Tags: python

I want to show image during for iterations.

I encountered empty initial figure is generated during running.

however if i stop running the image appears.

What the problem is? I am using python 3.6.

```
    plt.ion()  # turn on interactive mode, non-blocking `show`
    for loop in range(0, 3):
        y = np.dot(x, loop)
        plt.figure()  # create a new figure
        plt.plot(x, y)  # plot the figure
        plt.show()  # show the figure, non-blocking
        _ = input("Press [enter] to continue.")  # wait for input from the user
        plt.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a little pause after `plt.show()`

```
plt.show()
plt.pause(0.001)
```